# how to process onClickEvent by View and parent ViewGroup?

Tags: android, android-layout

Each item in my `android.widget.Gallery` is a `LinearLayout` with an Image and a TextView.  I set the onClick handler of the ImageView, which fires, but now the Gallery does not work.  The Gallery no longer accepts clicking or swiping gestures if the user touches the image.  It works fine if they tough other areas like the TextView which does not consume the onClick event. Is there a workaround for this problem.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res /android"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:padding="3sp" android:orientation="vertical" android:gravity="center_horizontal"> 

 <ImageView android:id="@+id/image" android:src="@drawable/logo"
    android:layout_height="110dp" android:layout_width="130dp" android:layout_gravity="center"></ImageView>
<TextView android:text="TextView" android:id="@+id/imageDescript" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TextView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: paste your listener code, please

Comment: The layout is above.  If the onClick is attached to image than clicking image will gobble the event and gallery does not work, but clicking on text will work.  Likewise if you put any onClick listener on the text than clicking text will gobble the event and Gallery does not get the event so sliding etc does not work, but if you click on Image which does not have the onClick Gallery does work.

Comment: So how to have onClickListener without losing the click event for the LinearLayout ?

Answer (score 0):

You can extend the LinearLayour, and then override the onInterceptTouch method.

You can manage there if you want to keep the event in your Gallery layout, or send it to the inner ImageView